# How to move content from QListWidget to a QStringList with PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I have a dialog in which a user selects the files that needs, it adds (via QPushButton) in a QListWidget, my problem it's that I need to recover all the files from the QListWidget in a QStringList.

I tried like this, but something is wrong:

```
        self.file = QtCore.QStringList()
        archivos = self.file

        cuenta = self.ventana.listWidget.count()
        for index in range(cuenta):
            archivos.append(self.ventana.listWidget.item(index))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing `.text()` after the item:

```
    self.file = QtCore.QStringList()
    archivos = self.file

    cuenta = self.ventana.listWidget.count()
    for index in range(cuenta):
        archivos.append(self.ventana.listWidget.item(index).text())
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to add the selected item text value to a QStringList. Here's how to do it.

```
QStringList *mList = new QStringList();
QString currItem = ui->listWidget->currentItem()->text();
mList->append(currItem);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I found very useful your answer, but with some changes because I need all the items from the list and not just one, but this works.